# Performing stop of activity that is not resumed {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Was running my Android app on a 5.1.1 device (Nexus 9) when I got a sudden, strange crash. The process seemed to die when the app was trying to start a new activity (`startActivityForResult()` to be specific). I went to check out the logcat (no exception was thrown in the debugger) and saw this:

```
E/ActivityThread(13750): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}
E/ActivityThread(13750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3344)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
E/ActivityThread(13750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I thought it was odd that the exception is calling out the native settings app rather than my own since it decided to kill my process. Is this normal/is there something I can do to stop exceptions from a native app wiping out my process? Or perhaps am I misreading the exception entirely?